# Covering for office chair

Tags: material-selection, fabric, restoration

I am looking to add some material to the chair seen below that will hold up better than the current material that is covering the chair.
The chair is pretty comfortable, so I like to keep it like that.

I just need something for the back and bottom. The bottom of the seat is 20 by 18 inches and the back is 20 by 22 inches.

I checked online stores for options, but got overwhelmed by all the choices.

I am open to any ideas.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to buy a ready-made cover or get ideas for something you would make, yourself? The former wouldn't be on-topic for the site. For the latter, what kind of advice are you looking for, beyond what the customer reviews would tell you?

Comment: @fixer1234 I like making stuff and would prefer doing so.

Answer (score 5):

In theory it's not too hard to make your own custom chair cover.

First and foremost you'll need to measure your chair. Measure the seat and backrest separately and don't forget to measure the thickness of them. These measurements should give you a roughly box-shaped cover that you should draw on a piece of paper.

Next you'll need to think about closures. How will the box-shaped cover fit over the chair and most importantly: how will it stay on the chair? Do you want to use a zipper? Then you'll need a sturdy one, preferably with metal teeth. Do you want to incorporate a drawstring? that has to be a sturdy cord. Maybe some hooks and bars? Make sure to get the big ones that don't bend under force.

And lastly, think about where those closures have to go. You can decide whether you want to cover the backside of the backrest or save on fabric by leaving it mostly open (this influences the closures; a drawstring would probably be easiest for this open back). But you'll have to leave openings on the seat cover for the central column and all the levers. Draw a hole big enough for the mechanics in your sketch and where you want to put the closures.

From this sketch you should make a pattern. Redraw the sketch in full size on some packing paper or a paper tablecloth and don't forget to **add at least 1/2 inch or 1 cm seam allowance** to all sides. If you want a drawstring closure, add 1.5 inch / 4 cm seam allowance to the edges where the drawstring will be. Don't forget to label each piece like "backrest front" or "seat left side" before cutting the pieces. This helps you figure out how much fabric you'll need for it all.

You'll need a sturdy fabric. I suggest a plain cotton weave from the upholstery or outdoors section of a fabric store (either physical store or online). Especially the seat area must withstand a lot of wear and tear. Artificial fibers like acrylic or poly*something can feel sweaty and uncomfortable in hot weather. Read how wide the fabric is and try arranging the pattern pieces in that width, then measure how much length you need to fit all the pieces.

The rest is simply assembling the pattern from the fabric. My experience with chair covers is that they can be a very tight fit, so I suggest sewing the cover first with the widest stitch length your sewing machine offers. Then test the fit of your cover. If it's too tight, ripping out the stitches is quick and easy. If it fits, sew over the same lines a second time and then finish the seam to avoid fraying.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, you can use whatever fabric you think will be comfortable. Some may experience some additional wear, but you can patch or remake the piece as needed, so with comfort your main focus on the chair itself, you should similarly reflect that on the covering.

Consider your aesthetics as well. Do you want the cover to look professional? Or just be comfortable? Personally, as I don't generally have people looking at my desk chair much (the corners may occasionally appear on a webcam, but the back isn't high enough for more than that), I went for comfort on mine. The cover I have over my chair, which was sewn for its more damaged predecessor, is a very simple construction of a sewn envelope that slides down over the back, and a gathered piece using an elastic drawstring for the seat. I will admit, the construction could likely be slightly better, as the seat cover slides forward a bit--I'd recommend, perhaps, a laced pattern at the underside instead if you went for a similar construction, to prevent it from sliding.

I've been using this cover for a very long time (more than 10 years), and the wear on it is extremely minimal. I didn't use a heavy duty upholstery fabric, just basic blanket fleece I picked up on sale. The loose construction allowed me to switch it to my current chair when the old one finally broke down too much to continue using, meaning it even outlived the chair I constructed it for.

Ultimately, the answer you turn to depends on the result you wish to desire and the amount of work you wish to put in; Elmy's answer is a good one, with a more aesthetically pleasing, professional result in exchange for more effort. Mine is the "quick and dirty but still long-lived" version of a solution, and I'd imagine there's other options as well. Good luck to you, whichever path you choose to go down.

Comment: I could use some details please on how to make a cover.

Comment: @fixit7, that's really a separate question, and the details will depend on the specific cover you want to make. The initial brainstorming to identify all of the details and constraints for a design might require the kind of open-ended discussion that can be done in chat. Unfortunately, nobody frequents the site's chat room.

Comment: @fixit7 since I see in your duplicate question you are limited to sewing by hand, google "how to make a tie blanket" and use that principle with the description of pieces I provided here and some cut fleece to cover your chair. If you don't want tassels down the edge, work inside-out and turn them to the inside before pulling the cover over the chair.

Comment: @Allison C I edited my post using your suggestion.

Comment: @fixit7 I would recommend a new question with specifics to what you want (omit the photo of the chair and the details about it, ask about using the desired material in the desired technique only). Clarifying changes to questions are good, but you should avoid changes that negate existing answers.

Comment: I feel the picture is helpful. It shows where the wear is occurring. I have found that perfectionism can be a curse and a blessing. @Allison C

Comment: @fixit7, I imagine this question is getting frustrating for you. You're right about the picture and I rolled the question back. Allison C's suggestion about omitting the picture wasn't about this question, it was about a new question focused on the specifics of a particular design. It might be worth taking a short break from the question and then coming back to it with a fresh take. When we're really engrossed in something, it's easy to  miss things or interpret things from the wrong fixed perspective. Taking a break and coming back to it can create a fresh perspective.

Comment: @fixit7 as fixer1234 clarified, the picture is fine and valuable for this specific question. Stack Exchange works on a system of asking a single question and collecting answers; your question about "can I tie faux leather like a fleece blanket?" is a new question about technique selection with your material, where the chair itself is no longer important to the question. The new question is definitely a good one that's worth asking! But with a whole new Q&A for it so it's useful for future visitors :)

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually I got help from some helpful and willing giving people in various fabric stores. Sorry, but you were not very helpful. Allison C. was.

Comment: @fixit7, I try but don't always succeed.  :-)  It's great that you were able to get the information you needed.  Once you make the cover, consider posting a self-answered question to share the knowledge and technique.

Comment: @fixer1234I bought some 4 inch thick foam and a nice piece of denim fabric. The tailor will sew some elastic into the material so I can take it off in case I get a spill. I will post a pic of the final cushion when she finished it.

Comment: @Allison CI bought some 4 inch thick foam and a nice piece of denim fabric. The tailor will sew some elastic into the material so I can take it off in case I get a spill. I will post a pic of the final cushion when she finished it.